# Piston slap in remanned engine ... is this normal?

Tags: chevrolet, noise, truck

Disappointed. I felt comfortable taking my truck there. Now I don’t know. My old engine in my 1998 5.7 Chevy truck Z71 was awesome and very quiet with a 129,000 miles until a hole rusted in the cast iron block. I took my truck to this mechanic and he told me he would order me a long block remanufactured engine. Consists of cylinder block fitted with pistons, rings, connecting rods, crankshaft, timing chain, sprockets or Gears. 3 year 100,000 warranty. Pick it up tonight with Brake in oil in it and was told to change it in a 1000 miles with 5W30 synthetic Mobil.

I get all this but why does it have piston slap? I told him that I thought I heard lifters and it howled some. He told me that it sounded like piston slap and it will or should go away. I've heard stories about piston slap not being covered at times because it is under wear and tear. I don’t know but I just drove it home and am pretty upset about this piston slap noise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question? How do you know it's piston slap? If the new engine only had block, pistons, rings, connecting rods, crankshaft, & timing chain, that's actually a short block. You said there was a "whole [sic] rusted in the cast iron block"... cast iron blocks don't get rusted holes in them unless something pokes its head out ... like a rod.

Comment: My truck started leaking oil really bad behind the oil filter. Rootted out the cast iron block behind the oil filter adapter

Comment: Sounds like piston slap to me. Like I said even mechanic said that. He put the crate engine in. Came as a long block assembly with 4year warranty.  Mechanic told me 3 years 100.000

Comment: Gen 1 SBC is not known for piston slap unless one of two things: it has forged pistons and upon first startup (goes away when warmed up); something is wrong with the engine, namely the pistons are too small for the bores. In either case, piston slap does not go away. (Note: Early Gen 3 SBCs had piston slap, but yours is not that). It sounds to me like the mechanic doesn't want to warrant the labor they put into getting the engine in the truck. You need to push this back on them stating the warranty. The slap will not go away.